# Custom Salesforce objects or fields

Tags: database-design, salesforce

I want to push some new data to Salesforce and need to create some new objects to store this data in. Coming from a database background, I think I should create 6-10 custom objects and link them. One of the primary users of Salesforce, who has no background in programming or databases, in our organization thinks we should create 2-3 objects and then put lots of fields in those objects.

Is storing data in Salesforce different than other databases? I plan on flattening my tables somewhat. In my database I have probably 20 tables that I want to push to Salesforce (not including reference table). I think I can get it down to maybe 7 objects, but I'm getting push back from creating so many objects.

His concern with so many objects is that it'll be confusing and changes to one object will have impact to others. My concern is that we won't be able to efficiently store all this data in so few of objects without creating tons of fields that will mostly get left blank.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for [salesforce limits](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDEQFjAB&url=http://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf&ei=BX1uUpiQMoPpswbCwYD4Cg&usg=AFQjCNHFJHr5-kl7jtJDbnATdtT9uvfh9Q&bvm=bv.55123115,d.Yms&cad=rja) there are no major differences with any other DB and you should follow general design rules in this case sounds like you are right. Again just check that you are not exceding custom object limits for your org.

Answer (score 0):

Remember you are going to incur 2 kb per row of data storage. At $3k per annum per GB this can end up being expensive

The way pages will appear to users will be less user friendly if you have lots of junction objects (rather than say using pick lists).

Salesforce limits definitely encourage a less normalized form. This is a challenge, not just from a development perspective (finding the right level of normalization/balance on the platform) but the meta-challenge is explaining this to business and Salesforce admins. ;)